# How to get current coordinates in UIPinchGestureRecognizer? (IOS, SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have view on storyboard and ViewController for it.
I need move labels on my View.
I can move label at step, but can't understand how to move following the finger. How to get coordinats?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addLabel(50, y: 50)
    }

    func addLabel(x:CGFloat, y:CGFloat)
    {
        var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 21))
        label.center = CGPointMake(x, y)
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.text = "I'am a test label"
        label.userInteractionEnabled = true
        label.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "scale:"))
        self.view.addSubview(label)
    }

    func scale(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if let view = recognizer.view
        {
            switch(recognizer.state)
            {
                case .Began:
                    break
                case .Changed:
                    view.frame.origin.x+=10
                case .Ended, .Cancelled:
                    break
                default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look for this method `func translationInView(_ view: UIView?) -> CGPoint`
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPanGestureRecognizer/translationInView:

Comment: @user3351949 I can't see available method translationInView for my recognizer

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish?